# Resolver to filter a non-scalar type in AppSync / Amplify

Tags: aws-appsync, resolver

We are using AWS Amplify. This is my type

```
type Package @model {
  id: ID!
  desc: String!
  company: Company! @connection
  servicetype: ServiceType! @connection
  price: Float!
  active: Boolean!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

Amplify does not generate a filter option for listPackage to allow filtering on servicetype. My understanding is you need to add a custom query and resolver for this. I have added a query listPackageByServiceType but am confused on the resolver... cannot get it to work.

Is there a similar example of code I can follow? I cannot get the filter option to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a secondary index on your DynamoDB table based on that field, serviceType, you can do this with a query on that field.

Otherwise, the way to go is probably a scan with a filter on that field. See here for more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-scan

From that link, the scan mapping template would look like this (note that depending on what you have, pagination might be necessary):

```
{
"version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "Scan",
"index" : "fooIndex",
"filter" : {
    "expression" : "filter expression"
    "expressionNames" : {
        "#name" : "name",
    },
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":value" : ... typed value
    }
}
}
```